# Can't import IResolvers from graphql-tools

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-tools

`import { IResolvers } from "graphql-tools";`
I was trying to import IResolvers from graphql-tools and got the message Module: *'"../node_modules/graphql-tools"' has no exported member 'IResolvers'*.

My dependencies are:"apollo-server-express": "^3.1.2","graphql": "^15.5.1", "graphql-tools": "^8.1.0"

Is this because I am on apollo 3 instead of apollo 2 which has IResolver?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Migrating to Apollo Server 3#Removed exports](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#removed-exports) doc, many types, and interfaces has been removed including `IResolvers` interface.

There are two solutions:

1. Run `npm install graphql-tools@4.x` and import the symbol from `graphql-tools`.
2. Run `npm install @graphql-tools/utils` and import the `IResolvers` from `@graphql-tools/utils`

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/68690827-euhsj?file=/src/index.ts)